# How do I query objects near a point with Ruby Geocoder/Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, mongoid, geocoding

I am trying to do something like this:

```
if params[:q]
  loc = Geocoder.search(params[:q])[0]
  logger.info loc.coordinates
  @places = Place.near(loc.coordinates).paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page])
else
...
```

It manages to geocode the query string correctly, but doesn't let me query against it.
Querying a model that uses geocoder raises the following error when you try to find objects near specific coordinates:

```
Mongo::OperationFailure
geo values have to be numbers
```

The app is running Mongoid, with the [Ruby Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem for geocoding.

**UPDATE** Here is the output of the geocode result:

```
    <Geocoder::Result::Google:0x102fe38c0 @data={"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"627", "types"=>["street_number"], "short_name"=>"627"}, {"long_name"=>"3rd Ave", "types"=>["route"], "short_name"=>"3rd Ave"}, {"long_name"=>"Manhattan", "types"=>["sublocality", "political"], "short_name"=>"Manhattan"}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "types"=>["locality", "political"], "short_name"=>"New York"}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"], "short_name"=>"New York"}, {"long_name"=>"New York", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"], "short_name"=>"NY"}, {"long_name"=>"United States", "types"=>["country", "political"], "short_name"=>"US"}, {"long_name"=>"10017", "types"=>["postal_code"], "short_name"=>"10017"}], "types"=>["street_address"], "partial_match"=>true, "geometry"=>{"location"=>{"lng"=>-73.9750644, "lat"=>40.7498908}, "bounds"=>{"northeast"=>{"lng"=>-73.9750644, "lat"=>40.7498994}, "southwest"=>{"lng"=>-73.9750849, "lat"=>40.7498908}}, "location_type"=>"RANGE_INTERPOLATED", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lng"=>-73.9719270293198, "lat"=>40.7530427206802}, "southwest"=>{"lng"=>-73.9782222706802, "lat"=>40.7467474793198}}}, "formatted_address"=>"627 3rd Ave, New York, NY 10017, USA"}>
MONGODB development['places'].find({:coordinates=>{"$nearSphere"=>[-73.9750644, 40.7498908], "$maxDistance"=>0.00505209229513324}})
Completed   in 504ms

Mongo::OperationFailure (geo values have to be numbers):
  app/controllers/places_controller.rb:11:in `index'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:17:in `call'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:17:in `call'
```

Comment: show us loc.coordinates value. Do you use ruby 1.9.2? there is some difference between 1.9.2 and 1.8.7 output for arrays, which geocoder returns.

Comment: @Mikhail - I updated the question with the entire result of the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mongoid query for Geospatial query is incorrect

instead this

```
@places = Place.near(loc.coordinates)
```

You have to use this

```
@places = Place.near(:loc => loc.coordinates).
```

**:loc** is the column/field name got the location co-ordinates in mongo document.

**Edit:**

And i forgot one more thing

Google geocoder returns the co-ordinates in **[lat,lng]** format, but mongo requires them in **[lng,lat]** format. You better reverse the co-ordinate in the query.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you need to be aware of when using Mongoid with Geocoder. Make sure you've included the Mongoid specific lines in your Place model.

Also, switch `loc.coordinates` to `loc.to_coordinates` otherwise you'll end up in Antarctica when you're looking for New York.

Comment: I tried that, and it raises "undefined method `to_coordinates' for #<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x102c7d2f8>"